# JQuery Datepicker is not working when appending new row - JQuery UI

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have a `datepicker` in a table. the `<tr>` appends when `button` clicked.

It's work fine when populate 1st `<tr>` but when 2nd `<tr>` created on `button` click, `datepicker` is not working.

### Check My [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/huzaifaabbas5253/awLbco0p/16/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code should do the trick. You need to remove the `id` from the date input. Since, `datepicker` uses the id internally and this must be unique. Also, in case you still need ids on each field. I added a counter, so that you could create unique ids for each row.

```
// Variable that we will be using to create unique ids.
var counter = 0;

$('#addnew').click(function () {

        //Creating <tr> for cheque details
        var tr = $("<tr><td class='banks'><input type=\"text\" class=\"form-control Product\" name=\"Product"+ counter +"\" id=\"Product"+ counter +"\" placeholder=\"Product\"></td>"
        + "<td><div>"
        + "<div class=\"input-group date\">"
        + "<div class=\"input-group-addon\"><i class=\"fa fa-calendar\"></i>"
        + "</div>"
        + "<input type=\"text\" class=\"form-control Date\" name=\"ChqDate\" id=\"Datet"+ counter +"\" placeholder=\"Date\">"
        + "</div><!-- /.input group -->"
        + "</div></td>"
        + "<td><input type=\"text\" name=\"Price\" class=\"form-control\" id=\"Pricet"+ counter +"\" placeholder=\"Price\" /></td>"
        + "<td><button data-itemId=\"0\" type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-danger removeRow\">remove</button></td></tr>");

        //append <tr> into table <tbody>

        $('#example1 tbody').append(tr);
        $(tr).find('.Date').datepicker({
                autoclose: true
        });

        counter++;

});
```

Hope it works.

Comment: I am glad I was of help! :)